# Image Slideshow using JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, image, swing

I have a problem with a task that seemed to be pretty easy. I have to create a program that will show images (.jpg,.png and .gif) consecutively. Images have to be the contents of some files, that is given as an argument to the program. When I have to load the images separately, it works, but the issue occurs when I load them one after another with a sleep between them.
Here is my code:

```
  import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
          @Override
          public void run()  
          {
            new MyFrame(args[0],Integer.parseInt(args[1])); 
    //First argument is path to file with images, second - amount of time (in seconds) which every image has to stay on the screen until the next one appears
          }
        });
      }
    }


import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    public MyFrame(String path, int time){
        super("Obrazki");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.add(panel);
        pack();
        File file = new File(path);
        String[] tabs = file.list();
        for(int i=0; i<tabs.length; i++)
        {
            panel.loadImage(path+"\\"+tabs[i]);
            this.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel 
{
  Image img;

  public void loadImage(String s)
  {
     img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(s);
     MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
     tracker.addImage(img, 1);
     while(!tracker.checkID(1)) {
         try {
            tracker.waitForID(1);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     this.repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
     g2.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height, this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the issue is when i load them one after another with sleep time between them.

You are causing the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` to sleep, which means the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Don't use Thread.sleep() when code is executing on the `EDT`.

For animation you can:

1. use a `SwingWorker` (with Thread.sleep())and publish the Icon you want to paint, or
2. use a Swing Timer. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Swing Timers`.